# GitAhead Large File Storage

Tags: git-lfs, gitahead

Does GitAhead support Large File Storage? I attempted to clone one of our BitBucket repositories.  It completed OK, but a large TAR file came down as only 1KB instead of several hundred MB.

I looked for a way to enable LFS and did not find one. Do I have to install a Plug-in?

Answer (score 1):

According to [an issue](https://github.com/gitahead/gitahead/issues/127) on their issue tracker, you need to manually install git-lfs and make it available to the `$PATH` available to GitAhead.

Usually, you can achieve this by installing git-lfs to a system-global location. Depnding on your OS, you can find suitable installation packages at https://git-lfs.github.com/ or https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/releases/.